# Are 'rahman' and 'ghafoor' synonymous or different according to Islamic literature?

Tags: names

Are 'rahman' and 'ghafoor' synonymous or different according to Islamic literature?
I searched online and found similar meanings for these two ('Gracious' & 'Forgiving' respectively).
What do the Islamic scriptures say in this regard?